# How to find both IPv6 and IPv4 with PHP?

Tags: php, server, ipv6, ipv4

When I look up my ip address on a website, it offers both my IPv6 and IPv4 address. When I use a PHP-script it only return the IPv6 address (both $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')).

How do these websites get my IPv4 address?

I have looked into all the $_SERVER variables but cannot find it.

Comment: Think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245053/how-can-i-get-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-using-php-code is relevant

Comment: If you're using a Hosting Control Panel like CPanel or Plesk it will have a REST API with which you can interrogate the settings of your websites, including the IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to run the website on three different host names:

- the normal one which resolves to both IPv4 and IPv6
- one that only resolves to IPv4
- one that only resolves to IPv6

On the last two, put a script that returns or stores the client’s IP address. Make the client visiting the website on the normal host name connect to the other two and include an identifier so the requests can be linked together in some way, and collect the resulting data.